# Catchwords and marginpars

Tags: marginpar

I am trying to make a document both with catchwords (first words from the next page) and with margin notes.

Is it possible to make `fwlw` and `marginpar` work together? Sometimes catchwords disappear, sometimes marginpars move or disappear.

MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{betababel}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage[a5paper, textwidth=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\newcommand{\klm}{\marginpar[\hfill{}111]{222}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\unhbox\NextWordBox}
однажды в студеную{\klm} зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 1
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 2
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 3
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 4
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 5
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 6
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 7
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 8
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 9
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 10
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 11
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 12
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из {\klm}лесу вышел был сильный мороз 13
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 14
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 15
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is surely some incompatibility between `fwlw` and `mparhack`.

Anyway, you can use `marginnote` for your margin notes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{betababel}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage[a5paper, textwidth=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\klm}{\marginnote[111]{222}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\unhbox\NextWordBox}
однажды в студеную{\klm} зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 1
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 2
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 3
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 4
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 5
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 6
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 7
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 8
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 9
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 10
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 11
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 12
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из {\klm}лесу вышел был сильный мороз 13
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 14
однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 15
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This does not solve the problem completely: if you modify the line `\hbox{однажды} в{\klm} студеную зимнюю пору я из лесу вышел был сильный мороз 7` you get `111 в` brought to the 1st page by `fwlw`

Comment: @pantlmn I can see no problems if you don't put `однажды` inside `\hbox`

Comment: The problem is that \NextWordBox grabs not only the text, but also the **margin note** from the first line on the odd page -- and I do not want this. Is it possible to hide somehow margin note from being grabbed? Maybe by `background` package?

Comment: @pantlmn Why do you need `однажды` to be inside `\hbox`? Without the `\hbox` the contents of the margin note is not grabbed.